# Retrieving data from multiple tasks from different threads

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

Good evening,

I have a List of different URLs (about 500) which content I get from this method

```
public static String getWebContent(URL url){
 // create URL, build HTTPConnection, getContent of page
}
```

after this I have another method where the content is fetched for values etc.
At this time I do it like this:

```
List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> webcontents = new ArrayList<>();
    for(URL url : urls){
         webcontents.add(getWebContent(url));
    }
// Futher methods to extract values from the webcontents
```

But it actually takes a lot of time, because there is only one Thread doing it. I wanted to make it multithreaded, but I am not sure what's the best way how to do it.

First, I need the return value of every Thread, should I implement `Callable` instead of `Runnable` for it?

And how do I run the method with different Threads, should there be one starting with index 0, one with index 50, etc.? And when they are done with one URL they set a flag to true? That would be my way, but it is not very effective I think. If the first website has a lot of content, the first Thread might take much longer then the others.

And when every Thread is done, how I can my data back to one list? Like this?

```
List<String> webcontent = new ArrayList<>();
    if(!t1.isAlive() && !t2.isAlive()){
        webcontent.add(t1.getData());
        webcontent.add(t2.getData());
    }
```

I hope you can understand my problem and can give me a tip :) Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use an `ExecutorCompletionService` to retrieve your tasks as they complete.

```
List<URL> urls = ...; // Create this list somehow
ExecutorCompletionService<String> service =
    new ExecutorCompletionService<String>(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10));
for (URL url: urls) {
    service.submit(new GetWebContentCallable(url)); // you need to define the GetWebContentCallable
}
int remainingTasks = urls.size();
while (remainingTasks > 0) {
    String nextResult = service.take();
    processResult(nextResult); // you define processResult
    remainingTasks -= 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could try something like:

```
public static List<String> getWebContents(final int threads, final URL... urls){
    final List<Future<String>> futures = new LinkedList<>();
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    Arrays.asList(urls).forEach(
            url -> {
                final Callable<String> callable = () -> {
                    try{
                        return getWebContent(url);
                    }catch(IOException ex){
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        return null;
                    }
                };
                futures.add(service.submit(callable));
            }
    );
    final List<String> contents = new LinkedList<>();
    futures.forEach(
            future -> {
                try{
                    contents.add(future.get());
                }catch(Exception ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
    );
    service.shutdown();
    return contents;
}
```

Of if you're not using Java 8:

```
public static List<String> getWebContents(final int threads, final URL... urls){
    final List<Future<String>> futures = new LinkedList<Future<String>>();
    final ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
    for(final URL url : urls){
        final Callable<String> callable = new Callable<String>(){
            public String call(){
                try{
                    return getWebContent(url);
                }catch(IOException ex){
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }
        };
        futures.add(service.submit(callable));
    }
    final List<String> contents = new LinkedList<String>();
    for(final Future<String> future : futures){
        try{
            contents.add(future.get());
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    service.shutdown();
    return contents;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of retrieving values from working threads, let working threads put results in a resulting collection (be it `List<String> webcontent` or anything else). Note this may require synchronization.